# Problems merging local and remote tables using SAS, using the 'dbkey=' optionnot working when

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I have some code to merge a local table of keys in SAS with a remote table (from a MS-SQL database).

Example code:

```
 LIBNAME RemoteDB ODBC user=xxx password=yyy datasrc='RemoteDB' READBUFF=1500;

 proc sql;
     create table merged_result as                      
     select t1.ID,
             t1.OriginalInfo,
             t2.RemoteInfo
    from input_keys as t1
    Left join RemoteDB.remoteTable (dbkey=ID)  as t2               
         on (t1.ID = t2.ID)
    order by ID;
 quit;
```

This used to work fine (at least for 150000 rows), but doesn't now, possibly due to SAS updates. At the moment, the same code leads to SAS trying to download the entire remote table (hundreds of GB) to merge locally, which clearly isn't an option. It is obviously the `dbkey=` option that has stopped working. For the record, the key used to join (ID in example) is indexed in the remote table.

Instead using the `dbmaster=` option together with the `multi_datasrc_opt=in_clause` option work (in the LIBNAME statement), but only for 4500 keys and less. Trying to merge larger datasets again leads to SAS trying to download the entire remote table.

Suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underwater's question indicates the implicit pass-through feature had worked previously in a manner consistent with optimized processing.  After an update the implicit pass-through continues to work for his queries, albeit in a non-optimal way.

To ensure a known (explicit) equivalent near optimal processing methodology I would upload `input_keys` to a temp table in RemoteDB and join that remotely in pass through.  This code is an example of a workable fallback whenever you are dissatisfied with the implicit decisions made by the Executor, SQL planner, and library engine.

```
LIBNAME tempdata oledb ... dbmstemp=yes ; * libname for remote temp tables;

* store only ids remotely;        
data tempdata.id_list;
  set input_keys(keep=id);
run;

* use uploaded ids in pass-through join, capture resultset and rejoin for OriginalInfo in sas;
proc sql;
  connect to ... as REMOTE ...connection options...;

  create table results_matched as
  select 
    RMTJOIN.* 
  , LOCAL.OriginalInfo
  from 
  (
    select * from connection to remote
    (
      select * 
      from mySchema.myBigTable BIG 
      join tempdb.##id_list LIST 
        on BIG.id = LIST.id
    )
  ) as RMTJOIN
  JOIN input_keys as LOCAL
    on RMTJOIN.id = LOCAL.id
  ;
quit;
```

The `dbmstemp` option for SQL Server connections causes new remote tables to reside in `tempdb` schema and be named with leading ##.

When using SQL Server use the `BULKLOAD=` libname option for highest performance.  You may require a special `GRANT` from the data base administrator in order to bulk load.

Comment: Thanks alot, and I will look more closely at your solution later. I actually thought that I had solved it after, since removing the `order by` seemed to make the query work. However, after re-running a couple of times I'm now back to the same problems. Very weird and frustrating.  

When you write "*...implicit pass-through feature is not functioning as previously or as expected...*"; do you mean that this behavior is well known?

Comment: @fileunderwater He's referring to it not working for you.  Implicit pass-through is always dangerous to have this problem; it's up to SAS and the RDBMS whether it uses pass-through or downloads the whole table, and you can't actually control that unless you yourself upload the table keys (as Richard does).  Things changing in your data, or in your connection, or in SAS, or basically anything can affect that decision.

Comment: Thanks again - this solution works fine. The only drawback is that it requires a lot more code than the implicit solution (and is harder to understand for novice SQL-users), but is probably better for consistent results in scripts that are run regularly.